# How to update an object in Unity using parse.com

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

It might be me who do not understand the documentation but I simply cannot update an existing object in Parse.com from my Unity app? Here is how i am trying to do so:

```
var userImg = new ParseObject("Test");
userImg["score"] = 14567;
userImg["playername"] = "Mike";
Task saveTask2 = userImg.SaveAsync();
```

This just creates a new object? i would think that I have to define the ObjectId somewhere and have tried to insert it SaveAsync() but this is not right... Really hoping for help in this matter cause i am stuck now.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Have you checked how are they updating object? https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#objects-updating

Comment: When following this I create a new object? It seems like I need to put the original ObjectId somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can take 2 approaches here:

1. You can retrieve the object from Parse as you normally would, assign it some new values, and save it again. That's one way to go.
2. If you don't want to make 2 calls (one for retrieving, and one for saving), you could try something similar to the code [here](https://parse.com/questions/updating-a-field-without-retrieving-the-object-first) (note: this is in JS & Android, but should map to unity). If you have the id, you can just get a pointer to the object and just modify it!.

Hope this solves the problem!

Comment: Didn't know about the second approach, seems very efficient!